# Intellij IDEA - Stripe Mark Colors Not Applying?

Tags: intellij-idea

We created a dark theme and made the error stripe mark for "Unknown Symbol" pink. The preview shows the bars as pink, but even after restarting IDEA it does not apply. It seems like it is inheriting the "Error" stripe mark color and binding to it instead (which we made red).

I don't see a way to turn off the inheritance. Is there a way to change this behavior?

[image]